# How to hold on coroutine until condition is true Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

My code spawn waves of enemies. For example, I have 3 waves. There are 5 enemies in each of them. Using coroutine  I generate them. But at the same time, immediately after the generation of the first wave of enemies, the initialization of the next wave begins. But the enemies from the very first wave have not yet finished their route. Therefore, I want to add the code so that the initialization of the second wave does not start until the enemies from the first wave have disappeared from the scene.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] List<WaveConfig> waveConfigs; // Here is config where i'm put a few waves ( for exmaple 3 waves with 5 enemies in each one)
    [SerializeField] int startingWave = 0;
    [SerializeField] bool looping = false;



    IEnumerator Start() //start courutine
    {
        do
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllWaves());
        }
        while (looping);

    }


    private IEnumerator SpawnAllWaves() //coururent to spawn Enemies waves one by one
    {
        for (int waveIndex = startingWave; waveIndex < waveConfigs.Count; waveIndex++)
        {
            var currentWave = waveConfigs[waveIndex];
            yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemiesInWave(currentWave)); //call coroutine to spawn all Enemies in wave.
        }

    }


    private IEnumerator SpawnAllEnemiesInWave(WaveConfig waveConfig) //Here is spawning each Enemies in particular wave
    {
        for (int enemyCount = 0; enemyCount < waveConfig.GetNumberOfEnemies(); enemyCount++)
        {
            var newEnemy = Instantiate(
                waveConfig.GetEnemyPrefab(),
                waveConfig.GetWaypoints()[0].transform.position,
                Quaternion.identity); //place enemy on scene
            newEnemy.GetComponent<EnemyPathing>().SetWaveConfig(waveConfig); //set them pay to move on scene
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveConfig.GetTimeBetweenSpawns()); //wait when next enemy in wave will generate

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: After `yield return StartCoroutine` in `SpawnAllWaves` you could yield in a loop until they have finished such as `while(enemiesNotFinished){yield return null;}`

Comment: If you want to wait in start till its happened like that your app will appear to hang. So totally negating why you put it in a coroutine. If you want to have something happen on finishing the coroutine. Why not put it in the end of that. Like “wave_spawned”

Comment: Seems like what you looking for is [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your enemy have a class like e.g.

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Keeps track of all existing (alive) instances of this script
    private static readonly HashSet<Enemy> _instances = new HashSet<Enemy>();

    // return the amount of currently living instances
    public static int Count => _instances.Count;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Add yourself to the instances
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // on death remove yourself from the instances
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

And then you can simply wait for

```
private IEnumerator SpawnAllWaves()
{
    for (int waveIndex = startingWave; waveIndex < waveConfigs.Count; waveIndex++)
    {
        var currentWave = waveConfigs[waveIndex];
        yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemiesInWave(currentWave));

        // After spawning all wait until all enemies are gone again
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => Enemy.Count == 0);
    }
}
```